# GAP Root Paths: Cannot find any files

Tags: gap-system

I am trying to install GAP on my PC, but am not having much luck with the root directory. On my work computer, I can put a file "test.g" in `C:\gap4r8\`, call `Read("test.g")` and it will load. However, this does not work on my home PC; I get:

```
Error, file "test.g" must exist and be readable called from
<function "unknown">( <arguments> )
```

Specifying the full path (e.g. `Read("C:/gap4r8/test.g"`), however, works fine.

Calling `GAPInfo.RootPaths` I get:

```
[ "/cygdrive/c/Users/Mark/_gap/", "/proc/cygdrive/C/gap4r8/" ]
```

The first folder (presumably `C:\Users\Mark\_gap\`) does not exist on my system, but strangely if I put "test.g" into `C:\Users\Mark\`, it will run just fine from `Read("test.g")`.

Running `.g` files from my own directory instead of from `C:\gap4r8\` is fine, but ideally I would like to move these to some subdirectory (e.g. `C:\Users\Mark\GAPscripts\`). But since I cannot access the current `GAPInfo.UserGapRoot` directory (`C:\Users\Mark\_gap\`) because it doesn't exists, I cannot find `gap.ini` to edit this.

---

Things I have tried:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling GAP (twice).
- Explicitly calling the root folder by changing a line in `gap.bat` from

`start "GAP" C:\gap4r8\bin\i686-pc-cygwin-gcc-default32\mintty.exe -s 120,40 /proc/cygdrive/C/gap4r8/bin/i686-pc-cygwin-gcc-default32/gap.exe -l /proc/cygdrive/C/gap4r8 %*`

to

`start "GAP" C:\gap4r8\bin\i686-pc-cygwin-gcc-default32\mintty.exe -s 120,40 /proc/cygdrive/C/gap4r8/bin/i686-pc-cygwin-gcc-default32/gap.exe -l "c:\gap4r8" %*`

(this then correctly shows `"c:\gap4r8"` as one of the root paths, but `test.g` won't load).

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to create `_gap` directory yourself. The best way is to call from GAP `WriteGapIniFile();` which will also populate it with `gap.ini`. Call this function and see details in its output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, use  `WriteGapIniFile()` and see what is the ouput. This will create the folder `_gap` and inside it a `gap.ini` (which you can edit to customize gap).

Hope this helps.